# Google Query.Как написать запрос суммирующий ячейки по определенному параметру?

Tags: запрос, google-spreadsheet

Есть Массив данных `A` "Browser" `B` "Browser Version" `C` "Device Category" `D` "Sessions" `E` "Ecommerce Conversion Rate"
Задача: Разделить Браузеры (с версиями) по типу устройства, актуальные и устаревшие(по сеансам и конверсии).
Проблема: Нужно разделить только на PC и Mobile+Tablet(Tablet отдельно не нужно).
Версии браузеров в Mobile и Tablet могут совпадать(но иметь разные значения `D` и `E`). Поэтому нужно объединить Mobile и Tablet по `B` суммировав при этом `D`

Разделяющую часть удалось написать

`Query(Import;"Select B Where A = '"&A1&"' and C !='desktop' and ((D < "&'Данные для формул'!$B$1&") or (D > "&'Данные для формул'!$B$1&" and E =0)) order by B desc")`

Где `A1` = Названия браузера,
`Данные для формул'!$B$1` = количество сессий

Comment: А можете добавить больше данных? И желательно, что именно должно получится в итоге (показать на примере). Потому что не сильно понятно, что и как

Comment: @Сергей Пряничкин Вот [таблица](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SFd3TQ8Vgu07cVgnKYIDotzFDpPV_o2YNOwndSw-dxo/edit?usp=sharing) где идет разделение.  Например "65.0.3325.112" tablet имеет 95 сеансов и попадает в old а "65.0.3325.112" mobile имеет 115 сеансов и попадает в new. Надо чтобы  "65.0.3325.112" попал в new с сеансом 210